# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement hikari-lightbulb (from versions: none)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, discord

I am trying to install this python library `hikari-lightbulb` but there seems to be some sort of issue which is not letting it get installed.

The command on the github repository to install this library is `pip install hikari-lightbulb` but using that is giving the error:

`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement hikari-lightbulb (from versions: none)`

`ERROR: No matching distribution found for hikari-lightbulb` 
Any way I could install this package now?

Answer (score 1):

All versions, even the earliest `hikari-lightbulb` version 0.0.5 [require](https://pypi.org/project/hikari-lightbulb/0.0.5/) Python >=3.8.0, <3.10, that is Python 3.8 or 3.9. If your Python is 3.7 or 3.10 you cannot install the package.

Use Python 3.8 or 3.9.